# Vis.js increase default zoom level of word graph (Network module)

Tags: javascript, graphics, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm working on a web page which uses Vis.js to create a word graph. But the thing is that with the default zoom level, it's very  hard to see the words: 
[image]
But if I increase the zoom level, then things work fine: 
[image]
So I really want to increase the default zoom level, so that an user doesn't have to zoom in on the word graph. Please help me, thank you very much: 
Here is the code: (I have also posted a demo online: http://word-graph-example.co.nf/index.html)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">       
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <title>DEMO</title>         
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.css"></script>       
    </head>
    <body>          
        <div id = "word_graph" style = "height: 500px;" class = "display" width = "100%"></div>        
        <script>
// Word graph (hacked from http://132.234.113.15:3000/getWordsGraph)
var network;
var allNodes;
var allEdges;
var highlightActive = false;
var nodesDataset;
var edgesDataset;
function redrawAll() {
    var container = document.getElementById('word_graph');
    var options = {     
        height: '100%',
        nodes: {
            shape: 'circle',
            scaling: {
                min: 10,
                max: 30,
                label: {
                    min: 8,
                    max: 30,
                    drawThreshold: 2,
                    maxVisible: 200
                }
            },
            font: {
                size: 12,
                face: 'Tahoma'
            }
        },
        edges: {
            width: 1,
            color: {
                inherit: 'source'
            },
            smooth: {
                type: 'continuous'
            }
        },
        interaction: {
            tooltipDelay: 200,
            hideEdgesOnDrag: false
        },
        layout: {           
            improvedLayout: false
        },
        physics: {
            //enabled: false,
            stabilization: {
                iterations: 500
            },
            barnesHut: {
                gravitationalConstant: -25000,
                centralGravity: 0.05,
                //centralGravity: 0,
                avoidOverlap: 1             
            },
            solver: 'barnesHut',
            minVelocity: 0.75
        },
        start: {
            zoomMin: 3
        }
    };  
        var jsonData = ....... // http://word-graph-example.co.nf/index.html for more information about the data, you can get it from that page :(
        nodesDataset = new vis.DataSet(jsonData.nodes);     
        edgesDataset = new vis.DataSet(jsonData.edges);

        var data = {nodes:nodesDataset, edges:edgesDataset};

        network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
        // get a JSON object
        // get a JSON object
        allNodes = nodesDataset.get({returnType:"Object"});
        allEdges = edgesDataset.get({returnType:"Object"});
    //network.focusOnNode(1,{scale: 2});    
        network.on("click", neighbourhoodHighlight);
}

function neighbourhoodHighlight(params) {
    // if something is selected:
    if (params.nodes.length > 0) {
        highlightActive = true;
        var i,j;
        var selectedNode = params.nodes[0];

        // mark all nodes as hard to read.
        for (var nodeId in allNodes) {
            allNodes[nodeId].color = 'rgba(200,200,200,0.5)';
            if (allNodes[nodeId].hiddenLabel === undefined) {
                allNodes[nodeId].hiddenLabel = allNodes[nodeId].label;
                allNodes[nodeId].label = undefined;
            }
        }
        for(var edgeId in allEdges){
            if(allEdges[edgeId].hiddenLabel === undefined){
                allEdges[edgeId].hiddenLabel = allEdges[edgeId].label;
                allEdges[edgeId].label = undefined;
            }
        }
        var connectedNodes = network.getConnectedNodes(selectedNode);
        var connectedEdges = network.getConnectedEdges(selectedNode);
        // all first degree nodes get a different color and their label back
        for (i = 0; i < connectedNodes.length; i++) {
            allNodes[connectedNodes[i]].color = 'rgba(51, 204, 51,0.75)';
            if (allNodes[connectedNodes[i]].hiddenLabel !== undefined) {
                allNodes[connectedNodes[i]].label = allNodes[connectedNodes[i]].hiddenLabel;
                allNodes[connectedNodes[i]].hiddenLabel = undefined;
            }
        }
        // all first degree edges
        for (i = 0; i < connectedEdges.length; i++) {
            if (allEdges[connectedEdges[i]].hiddenLabel !== undefined) {
                allEdges[connectedEdges[i]].label = allEdges[connectedEdges[i]].hiddenLabel;
                allEdges[connectedEdges[i]].hiddenLabel = undefined;
            }
        }
        // set the color for the main(clicked) node
        allNodes[selectedNode].color = 'rgba(255, 51, 0, 0.75)';
        if (allNodes[selectedNode].hiddenLabel !== undefined) {
            allNodes[selectedNode].label = allNodes[selectedNode].hiddenLabel;
            allNodes[selectedNode].hiddenLabel = undefined;
        }
    }
    else if (highlightActive === true) {
        // reset all nodes
        for (var nodeId in allNodes) {
            allNodes[nodeId].color = undefined;
            if (allNodes[nodeId].hiddenLabel !== undefined) {
                allNodes[nodeId].label = allNodes[nodeId].hiddenLabel;
                allNodes[nodeId].hiddenLabel = undefined;
            }
        }
        for (var edgeId in allEdges) {
            allEdges[edgeId].color = undefined;
            if (allEdges[edgeId].hiddenLabel !== undefined) {
                allEdges[edgeId].label = allEdges[edgeId].hiddenLabel;
                allEdges[edgeId].hiddenLabel = undefined;
            }
        }
        highlightActive = false
    }

    // transform the object into an array
    var nodeUpdateArray = [];
    for (nodeId in allNodes) {
        if (allNodes.hasOwnProperty(nodeId)) {
            nodeUpdateArray.push(allNodes[nodeId]);
        }
    }
    nodesDataset.update(nodeUpdateArray);
    var edgeUpdateArray = [];
    for (edgeId in allEdges) {
        if (allEdges.hasOwnProperty(edgeId)) {
            edgeUpdateArray.push(allEdges[edgeId]);
        }
    }
    edgesDataset.update(edgeUpdateArray);
}

redrawAll();

var selectedNode = network.selectNodes(['580']); // GreatBarrierReef    
console.log(selectedNode);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code for twiddling with the options:

```
var options = {     
            height: '100%',
            nodes: {
                shape: 'circle',
                scaling: {
                    min: 10,
                    max: 30,
                    label: {
                        min: 8,
                        max: 30,
                        drawThreshold: 2,
                        maxVisible: 200
                    }
                },
                font: {
                    size: 12,
                    face: 'Tahoma'
                }
            },
            edges: {
                width: 1,
                color: {
                    inherit: 'source'
                },
                smooth: {
                    type: 'continuous'
                }
            },
            interaction: {
                tooltipDelay: 200,
                hideEdgesOnDrag: false
            },
            layout: {           
                improvedLayout: false
            },
            physics: {
                //enabled: false,
                stabilization: {
                    iterations: 500
                },
                barnesHut: {
                    gravitationalConstant: -25000,
                    centralGravity: 0.05,
                    //centralGravity: 0,
                    avoidOverlap: 1             
                },
                solver: 'barnesHut',
                minVelocity: 0.75
            },
            start: {
                zoomMin: 3
            }
```

Please help me, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

i think u can try like this:

```
network.moveTo({scale: 0.5})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use after the image is drawn:

```
network.focus(18, {scale: 0.5}) // Node id = 18.
```